# Will the Stack Exchange API work with an org-specific Stack Overflow site?

Tags: support, api, stackoverflow

We have a company-specific Stack Overflow site for folks to ask questions with the company. It has a `*.stackoverflow.com` domain/URL.

Would I be able to use the Stack Exchange API to access the questions, etc. from that site?
I'd like to create a tool to get insights from it and share it internally. If not, are there any other options available?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using [*Stack Overflow Enterprise*](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise)?  If so, [API support was promised for right about now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286830/148310)<sup>There's a chance that ETA might slip. ;)</sup>.

Otherwise, how exactly is this company-specific site configured?  If it's not either in [**this** list of sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=!*l7am74vWNfdoRA*cxv_*)0Q&run=true), or visible to the general public on regular Stack Overflow, then you have no API support for now.  Contact your account manager at Stack Exchange for more info.